# Unresolved reference: indices

Tags: kotlin

everyone. Am new to kotlin. Does anyone have solution to this syntax error am experiencing. the key word "indices in my code keeps flagging an error that says unresolved reference: indices. I have tried update my build.gradle with id 'kotlin-android-extensions' but it seems not to solve the problem.

```
fun detachCounter(row: Int , col: Int) {
        var index = -1
        for (i in catalog.indices) {
            if (catalog[i].col == col && catalog[i].row == row) {
                index = i
                break
            }
        }
        if (index != -1) {
            catalog.removeAt(index)
            _draughBoard[row][col] = 0
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the type of your `catalog` variable?

Comment: What type is `catalog`? Can you add the code where you declared it?

Comment: I initialized it here   init {
        _draughBoard = Array(8) { IntArray(8) }
        catalog = ArrayList()
        initialize()
    }

Comment: the catalog there is a variable:   val catalog: ArrayList<DraughtCounters>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *catalog* is an ArrayList of a class *DraughtCounters* your code should work. I tested it with a very simple *DraughtCounters* class:

```
class DraughtCounters(var row: Int = 0, var col: Int = 0)

val catalog = arrayListOf(
  DraughtCounters(1, 1),
  DraughtCounters(1, 2),
  DraughtCounters(1, 3),
  DraughtCounters(2, 1),
  DraughtCounters(2, 2),
  DraughtCounters(2, 3),
  DraughtCounters(3, 1),
  DraughtCounters(3, 2),
  DraughtCounters(3, 3)
)

... your detachCounter function code here ...

detachCounter(1, 2)
detachCounter(2, 3)
detachCounter(3, 1)

for (item in catalog) {
  println("${item.row}, ${item.col}")
}
```

If that is indeed your setup with *catalog* and *DraughtCounters* then you can further simplify *detachCounter* to something like this:

```
fun detachCounter(row: Int, col: Int) {
  val itemToDetach = catalog.firstOrNull { it.row == row && it.col == col }
  if (itemToDetach != null) {
    catalog.remove(itemToDetach)
    // _draughBoard[itemToDetach.row][itemToDetach.col] = 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for also coming through.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the error by simply updating my build. gradle dependecies

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```